# One Trust scripts not allowing to dequeue the style for specific template file in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I was trying to dequeue the style.css and javascriptmain.js for a template. For that I was using the below hooks to dequeue the style and script in functions.php. And after this snippet there is nothing written in functions.php file.

```
function project_dequeue_unnecessary_styles() {
    if(is_page_template('landing-pages/first_lp.php')){
    wp_dequeue_style( 'meta-global-style' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'meta-global-style' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', 'project_dequeue_unnecessary_styles', 999 );

//Dequeue JavaScripts
function project_dequeue_unnecessary_scripts() {
    if(is_page_template('landing-pages/first_lp.php')){
    wp_dequeue_script( 'main-script' );
    wp_deregister_script( 'main-script' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', 'project_dequeue_unnecessary_scripts', 999 );
```

I believe nothing wrong with this approach. Even after dequeue the style is getting populated in the template front-end but the JavaScript is getting dequeued. Seems strange for me. After hours of searching I have found that the one trust cookie scripts in the header causing this issue. Can anyone tell me how can i avoid this issue in WordPress?

Comment: `999` might be too late, maybe try `0`. Or, maybe try another action like `wp_enqueue_scripts` and use `999` there